# UITableViewCell doesn't show content

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using Xcode 5, and developing an app targeted to iOS6/7.

In my storyboard, the "prototype cells", that refer to custom class "ObjListCell", derived from "UITableViewCell", contains a "Content View" that in turn contains a UIImageView and two UILabel elements. All three of them are connected to an IBOutlet in my ObjListCell class.

The table view controller refers to my custom class "ObjListViewController", derived from "UITableViewController". When this view controller is created, I have already retrieved the data, so in the viewDidLoad i call `[self.tableView reloadData];` right away. But before doing so, i register the cell class: `[self.tableView registerClass: [ObjListCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"objTableCell"];` and "objTableCell" is set in the storyboard as the identifier for the cells.

Method numberOfRows in section returns 14, and I actually see a list with 14 empty rows on my iPhone. As I can see from the logs, method cellForRowAtIndexPath is actually called, and method dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier returns a non-nil cell. So I set the icon and label content:

```
cell.mCellIcon.image = icon;
cell.mCellTitle.text = title;
cell.mCellExtra.text = extra;
```

I am sure the icon and text are OK, because I log them just before assigning them.
But nevertheless, my table cells appear empty.

Can anyone suggest where the problem could be?

This is the whole code for cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"objTableCell";
    ObjListCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil)
        NSLog(@"ObjListViewController ERROR: Cell is nil");

    // Retrieve obj for this cell
    Obj* obj = [mObjs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (obj == nil)
        NSLog(@"ObjListViewController ERROR: Obj not found for cell; indexPath = %i", indexPath.row);
    NSLog(@"ObjListViewController DEBUG: title = %@, extra = %@", obj.mTitle, obj.mExtra);

    // Set cell icon
    UIImage *icon = [mIcons iconForId:obj.mId andSize:@"big" withDefault:@"defaultIcon"];
    if (icon == nil)
        NSLog(@"ObjListViewController ERROR: Icon not found for cell; indexPath = %i", indexPath.row);
    cell.mCellIcon.image = icon;

    // Set cell title and extra
    cell.mCellTitle.text = obj.mTitle;
    if (obj.hasExtra)
        cell.mCellExtra.text = obj.mExtra;
    NSLog(@"ObjListViewController DEBUG: Inspecting cell content; icon = %@, title = %@, extra = %@",
     (cell.mCellIcon.image != nil ? @"OK" : @"nil"), cell.mCellTitle.text, cell.mCellExtra.text);

    // Standard accessory symbol
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}
```

And this is a excerpt of the log:

```
2014-02-16 15:21:06.665 trekking-etc-viewer[2671:60b] ObjListViewController DEBUG: title = Valle d'Aosta, extra = 
2014-02-16 15:21:06.668 trekking-etc-viewer[2671:60b] ObjListViewController DEBUG: Inspecting cell content; icon = nil, title = (null), extra = (null)
2014-02-16 15:21:06.685 trekking-etc-viewer[2671:60b] ObjListViewController DEBUG: title = Provincia di Belluno, extra = 
2014-02-16 15:21:06.690 trekking-etc-viewer[2671:60b] ObjListViewController DEBUG: Inspecting cell content; icon = nil, title = (null), extra = (null)
```

None of the "ERROR" log lines appear in the log.

Comment: did you change the cell's class to your custom class in IB ?

Comment: Yes I did. In the storyboard, I mean. I happen just now to discover that I hadn't synthesized the three IBOutlets in my ObjListCell.m file, but after fixing this the problem persists. I have also added a log to check the value of cell.mCellIcon.image, cell.mCellTitle.text and cell.mCellExtra.text, after assigning them their value: they are nil! But as I have said, the right-hand data before the assignments are OK.

Comment: Add `NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@", cell.mCellIcon, cell.mCellTitle, cell.mCellExtra);`. If it will show nil values - you forget to bind GUI elements to IBOtlet's.

Comment: In fact they are nil, but in the story board the three UI elements do have a referencing outlet, for example mCellIcon refers to ObjListCell. And when I inspect the IBOutlets in the ObjListCell.h file, a filled dot appears at the left of each one; this means they are correctly connected, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am definitely unable to make it work using a storyboard, despite the many suggestions and attempts. For sure I am missing some little tricky detail somewhere, but tools don't provide any useful help on the matter. So I reverted to NIBs, and so this is my answer for the moment.

I would like just to summarize the few things I have taken care not to miss in defining and using the cell's nib:

- In the NIB, set the table view controller as the file's owner
- In the NIB, set the cell identifier to the proper value (objListCell, for me)
- In the NIB, connect each UI element to an IBOutlet in the cell's .h file
- In the cell's .m file, perhaps synthesise the outlets, but if you don't, it works all the same
- In viewWillAppear of the table's .m file, register the NIB (see details below)
- In cellForRowAtIndexPath of the table's .m file, dequeue your cell (see details below)

Registering the nib:

```
UINib* cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"ObjListCell" bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:cellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"objListCell"];
```

Dequeueing the cell:

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"objListCell";
ObjListCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

All the rest is just as usual.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest placing [self.tableView reloadData] in viewWillAppear: as the tableView may not be available yet in viewDidload:.

Also, if I am having problems like this, I will give my objects borders to see if they are actually placed where I expect them to be:

```
label.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
label.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
```

How about trying the following in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"objTableCell";

ObjListCell *cell = (ObjListCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (!cell)
{
    cell = [[DDTripCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

Comment: Thank you Nick, I moved [self.tableView reloadData] to viewWillAppear, but this did not solve the problem. I also added the border colouring as suggested, but nothing appears. In addition, in the storyboard I set tags for Content View, the icon and the two labels. Then tried to find the respective views by means of viewWithTag, but got nil. It looks like the prototype cell defined in the storyboard does not work at all... And finally, if I override the initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier in the ObjListCell class and put a NSLog in it, I see it is called.

Comment: Could you paste your cellForRowAtIndexPath:, which may help in identifying the problem?

Comment: Edited the original question to add these details. mObjs is an array containing the data to show in the list; it is already loaded when the table view controller is created. mIcons is a container where icons are contained. It initially provides default icons; the actual icons are loaded subsequently, but this is another story...

Comment: @GiorgioBarchiesi I have updated my answer with a suggestion to try in your cellForRowAtIndexPath: method.

Comment: If this is still causing problems, feel free to email your project to me at "admin at myfirstiphoneapp dot co dot uk", so that I can take a proper look.

Comment: Thank you very much, but the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier never returns nil, since I have registered the cell class in the viewWillAppear, before reloading the table. I have implemented several table view controllers before, but I used to use nibs, this is the first time with a storyboard. So far, it is proving a huge waste of time... I'll vote you up, because you suggested several useful ideas, but can not mark the answer as "the answer", sorry.

Comment: I should have mentioned removing the registering of the class in viewWillAppear:. This is how I implemented a UITableViewCell subclass, using a prototype cell in the storyboard.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier objTableCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard' So, shall I connect the prototype cell to something? I have specified the class and the identifier, and connected each single component view (icon+labels), is this not enough?

Comment: You will need to remove the cell identifier from the storyboard cell.

Comment: Same exception. Nick, it is very nice of you assisting me this way, but I need to stop working on this today, or I will end up throwing myself out of the window... ;-) I will surely post a comment if I can find and solve the trouble in the next days. In the worst case, I will throw way the storyboard and use plain old good NIBs.